# Is there a way to create backup and restore database (SQL Server) in JSP page?

Tags: jsp

I want to create a JSP page where for example there is a button that when you click will either backup or restore a database that comes from SQL Server. Is that possible and how? Thank you.

Comment: If there is a Microsoft SQL Server SQL command you can execute to accomplish that, you can execute it via JDBC.

Comment: @EJP how will I do that?